# My Firebase/Facebook Auth login works and will not display the users username in my next activity: activity_main.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, facebook, firebase-authentication

Here is my XML for my **activity_sign_in**

My task is to assign the user (once logged in) and have the Facebook username displayed in the next activity.

```js
< RelativeLayout xmlns: android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns: app = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns: tools = "http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android: id = "@+id/main_layout"
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "match_parent"
android: background = "@color/grey_100"
android: orientation = "vertical"
android: weightSum = "4" >

  <
  ImageView
android: id = "@+id/imageView"
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
app: srcCompat = "@drawable/new_green_360" / >

  <
  ProgressBar
android: id = "@+id/progressBar"
style = "?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
android: layout_width = "wrap_content"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: layout_centerHorizontal = "true"
android: layout_centerVertical = "true"
android: indeterminate = "true"
android: visibility = "gone" / >



  <
  RelativeLayout
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "0dp"
android: layout_weight = "3"
android: gravity = "center_horizontal"
android: orientation = "vertical" >

  <
  ImageView
android: id = "@+id/icon"
style = "@style/ThemeOverlay.FirebaseIcon"
android: layout_width = "wrap_content"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: contentDescription = "@string/desc_firebase_lockup"
android: src = "@drawable/firebase_lockup_400" / >

  <
  TextView
android: id = "@+id/title_text"
android: layout_width = "wrap_content"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: layout_marginBottom = "@dimen/title_bottom_margin"
android: text = "@string/emailpassword_title_text"
android: theme = "@style/ThemeOverlay.MyTitleText" / >

  <
  TextView
android: id = "@+id/status"
style = "@style/ThemeOverlay.MyTextDetail"
android: text = "@string/signed_out" / >

  <
  TextView
android: id = "@+id/detail"
style = "@style/ThemeOverlay.MyTextDetail"
tools: text = "Firebase User ID: 123456789abc" / >

  <
  /RelativeLayout>


  <
  RelativeLayout
android: layout_width = "fill_parent"
android: layout_height = "0dp"
android: layout_weight = "1"
android: background = "@color/grey_300"
android: gravity = "center_vertical" >

  <
  LinearLayout
android: id = "@+id/email_password_fields"
android: layout_width = "fill_parent"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: orientation = "horizontal"
android: paddingLeft = "16dp"
android: paddingRight = "16dp" >

  <
  EditText
android: id = "@+id/field_email"
android: layout_width = "0dp"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: layout_weight = "1"
android: hint = "@string/hint_email"
android: inputType = "textEmailAddress" / >

  <
  EditText
android: id = "@+id/field_password"
android: layout_width = "0dp"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: layout_weight = "1"
android: hint = "@string/hint_password"
android: inputType = "textPassword" / >
  <
  /LinearLayout>

  <
  LinearLayout
android: id = "@+id/email_password_buttons"
android: layout_width = "fill_parent"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: layout_below = "@+id/email_password_fields"
android: orientation = "horizontal"
android: paddingLeft = "16dp"
android: paddingRight = "16dp" >

  <
  Button
android: id = "@+id/email_sign_in_button"
android: layout_width = "0dp"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: layout_weight = "1"
android: text = "@string/sign_in"
android: theme = "@style/ThemeOverlay.MyDarkButton" / >

  <
  Button
android: id = "@+id/email_create_account_button"
android: layout_width = "0dp"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: layout_weight = "1"
android: text = "@string/create_account"
android: theme = "@style/ThemeOverlay.MyDarkButton" / >
  <
  /LinearLayout>

  <
  LinearLayout
android: id = "@+id/signed_in_buttons"
android: layout_width = "fill_parent"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: layout_centerInParent = "true"
android: orientation = "horizontal"
android: paddingLeft = "16dp"
android: paddingRight = "16dp"
android: visibility = "gone"
android: weightSum = "2.0" >

  <
  Button
android: id = "@+id/sign_out_button"
android: layout_width = "0dp"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: layout_weight = "1.0"
android: text = "@string/sign_out"
android: theme = "@style/ThemeOverlay.MyDarkButton" / >

  <
  Button
android: id = "@+id/verify_email_button"
android: layout_width = "0dp"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: layout_weight = "1.0"
android: text = "@string/verify_email"
android: theme = "@style/ThemeOverlay.MyDarkButton" / >

  <
  /LinearLayout>

  <
  /RelativeLayout>

  <
  com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
android: id = "@+id/loginButton"
android: layout_width = "wrap_content"
android: layout_height = "18dp"
android: layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
android: layout_centerHorizontal = "true"
android: layout_marginBottom = "75dp"
android: paddingBottom = "10dp"
android: paddingTop = "10dp" / >

  <
  />
```

Here is my **FacebookLoginActivity.java** code

```js
package com.transcendencetech.juliospizzaprototype;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Created by Stormy Forrester on 8/3/2016.
 */
public class FacebookLoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private LoginButton loginButton;
  private CallbackManager callbackManager;

  private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
  private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener firebaseAuthListner;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.sign_in_layout);

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);

    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback < LoginResult > () {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancel() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

      @Override
      public void onError(FacebookException error) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    });

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseAuthListner = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
      @Override
      public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
          goMainScreen();
        }
      }
    };
  }

  private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken accessToken) {
    AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken.getToken());
    firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener < AuthResult > () {
      @Override
      public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < AuthResult > task) {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.firebase_error_login, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthListner);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    firebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthListner);
  }

  public void goMainScreen() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
  }
}
```

Here is the next activity: **activity_main.xml**

```js
<< ? xml version = "1.0"
encoding = "utf-8" ? >
  <
  RelativeLayout xmlns : android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns: tools = "http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "match_parent"
android: background = "@color/color_bg"
tools: context = "com.transcendencetech.juliospizzaprototype.SignInActivity" >

  <
  include
android: id = "@+id/header"
layout = "@layout/header"
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: layout_alignParentTop = "true"
android: layout_alignParentLeft = "true"
android: layout_alignParentStart = "true" / >

  <
  RelativeLayout
android: id = "@+id/my_tabs"
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "40dp"
android: layout_below = "@id/header"
android: background = "@android:color/black" >

  <
  View
android: id = "@+id/divider_view"
android: layout_width = "1dp"
android: layout_height = "match_parent"
android: layout_centerInParent = "true"
android: layout_margin = "2dp"
android: background = "@android:color/white" / >

  <
  Button
android: id = "@+id/pizza_list_bt"
android: layout_width = "wrap_content"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: layout_alignParentLeft = "true"
android: layout_alignParentStart = "true"
android: layout_toLeftOf = "@id/divider_view"
android: layout_toStartOf = "@id/divider_view"
android: background = "@android:color/black"
android: inputType = "textPersonName"
android: text = "List of Pizzas"
android: textColor = "@android:color/white" / >

  <
  Button
android: id = "@+id/deals_list_bt"
android: layout_width = "wrap_content"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: layout_alignParentEnd = "true"
android: layout_alignParentRight = "true"
android: layout_toEndOf = "@id/divider_view"
android: layout_toRightOf = "@id/divider_view"
android: background = "@android:color/black"
android: inputType = "text"
android: text = "List of Deals"
android: textColor = "@android:color/white" / >
  <
  /RelativeLayout>

  <
  ImageView
android: id = "@+id/pizza_list_iv"
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "150dp"
android: layout_below = "@id/my_tabs"
android: scaleType = "fitXY"
android: src = "@drawable/list_pizza_header" / >

  <
  ListView
android: id = "@+id/list_view"
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "match_parent"
android: layout_below = "@id/pizza_list_iv"
android: divider = "@color/color_divider"
android: focusable = "true"
android: dividerHeight = "2dp"
android: layout_margin = "15dp" / >

  <
  include
layout = "@layout/footer"
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
android: layout_alignParentLeft = "true"
android: layout_alignParentStart = "true" / >

  <
  /RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the **SignInActivity.java**

```js
package com.transcendencetech.juliospizzaprototype;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;

public class SignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() == null) {
      goLoginScreen();
    }
  }

  private void goLoginScreen() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, FacebookLoginActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
  }

  public void logout(View view) {
    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
    goLoginScreen();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you are providing doesn't show any code that could set a TextView in your layout

```
public void goMainScreen() {
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);}
```

I think you have to show the code of SignInActivity

But it should work with something like that:

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();    
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.[YOUR_ID_OF_TEXTVIEW])).setText(user.getDisplayName());
```

Comment: SignInActivity.java snippet added

Comment: Hm ok, but there is still no code that actually could set the Text in a TextView. When you have a user logged in, you go to the SignInActivity with the method goMainScreen().
If you want you can check if you have a user in the onCreate method and if you have one use the code above to set the text of a TextView

Comment: Perhaps setContent()

Comment: on what would you use that method?
Which TextView do you want to change especially?

Comment: I will get back to you shortly.